# EXR-multilayer, Blender to Photoshop color management

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, color-management, .exr

I have rendered out rendering passes in EXR-multilayer from Blender to Photoshop and changed the color management in Photoshop using OpenColorIO to AGX, so it will match the color in Blender.

What I can't get to work is that in Blender I have changed the Color manamgenment, Look to "Very High Contrast" and I dont't understand how I can get that into my Photoshop.
Is there a way to solve this? How I would greatly appreciate some help.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151351/discussion-on-question-by-n03-exr-multilayer-blender-to-photoshop-color-managem); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.